# What should I do before applying organic fertilizer to ensure no bugs or smell?

Tags: pest-control, fertilizer, organic

Does all organic fertilizer require decomposing? I would like to focus on fertilizer available in gardening shops instead of unprocessed urine or manure from mammals.

As far as I know, decomposing of organic fertilizer require microbes in the soil and the action itself may have some undesired smell or it may attracts bugs.

If I want to avoid bugs and stinking smell, what should do before applying the fertilizer to the soil? Should I compost the fertilizer?

The reason of asking this is that I have an experience of using organic fertilizer in granule form bought from gardening shop. I put the granules on the surface of soil as instructed by the manual ( it said it is okay to put it on the soil or in the soil ). After some months ( I didn't look into the soil when I watered them ), I found there were quite a lot of ants moving in and out of my pot. Then as I checked the plant, I found the organic fertilizer granules covered with white fungus. I wonder if the fungus attracted the ants.

Answer (score 3):

If you're concerned about bugs, ants and smell, and know about composting, i would recommend compost tea. It's not supposed to smell and doesn't take long to make. You could use that to help feed your plants instead.